# How can I load an external array in to jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
<script>
var somevariable=somearray[x1,x2,x3......]
</script>
```

//Is there any way to define the someaaray externally, Like defining that array in to another external js or txt file and loading that in to the variable like load()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _define the array externally_ - what does it mean?

Comment: @Saral I meant like an another external js or external txt file,

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

index.js

```
var externalArr = require('./ext.js') // import externalArr from ext.js file
console.log(externalArr) // logs [1, 2, 3, 4] to the console
```

ext.js

```
var externalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

module.exports = externalArr // This will enable you to import externalArr from another file
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I am looking for, but its not working, Its showing error,

Answer (score 0):

Your `1.js` is a different file which has some code.

Your `2.js`uses the code and loads it inside the

```
 $(document).ready(fn);
```

**OR**

```
 $(fn);
```

```js
//1.js
var array= ['foo','bar'];

//2.js

$(function(){

console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by *define the someaaray externally and load that in to the somevariable*?

If you want to merge two arrays, you can do it using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [9, 8, 7];

var resultarray = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(resultarray);
```

Comment: Like defining that array in to another external js or txt file and loading that in to the variable like load() or something